# How do TV shows go about getting "unbranded" cars?

Tags: the-big-bang-theory

I was watching Episode 6 of Season 10 of the *Big Bang Theory*. In this episode, Howard tries to convince Bernadette that a minivan is a good idea, and he has one on a 24-hour test-drive from the dealership.

I don't live in the US, but I was able to make a pretty good guess that the minivan was probably a Chrysler (we get Chrysler Grand Voyagers down under) so did some poking around on Google, searching "chrysler minivan rear".

I found this image, which I compared to the rear of the minivan shown in the episode. It is apparently a 2016 Chrysler Town & Country.

[image: Chrysler minivan]

[image: Minivan as seen in episode]

The resemblance is quite striking, and the one used in the show probably is indeed the Town & Country. This led me to wonder, how do they do such a good job of masking the make and model?

Do they make a special order from a dealer? Do they use a professional auto detailer? Do they use CGI?

As you can see when comparing the two pictures, the one seen in the show is seemingly not a simple "take the badge off" trick; there is actually a blank badge within a sort of diamond where the Chrysler "wings" would ordinarily be spread. Furthermore, the stock model does not have a raised diamond and has lettering on the metal on the boot.

The practice of concealing automakers in this show, at least, is common, though one could clearly identify Penny's original car as a Volkswagen, and I think Bernadette's car is a Nissan.

Comment: Hmmmm...interesting.  Are there any other products on this show that conceal their brand or is it just automobiles?

Comment: @steelersquirrel Yes there are. You'll commonly see the gang drinking from unlabelled or fake-labelled plastic bottles. However, sometimes brands are chucked in if it's relevant; for example, Leonard '[owing] the Betty Crocker company a letter of apology' after finding out the cup he mixed pancake batter in was actually a cup used by Sheldon for measuring urine.

Comment: You can order cars badgeless - i.e. without any identifier other than the maker, no model details, it's usually to hide it being either a top prestige or base model. I used to own a badgeless BMW 7. The maker badge replacement may be as simple as a match for the original badge-holes & may be just push-fit. There are hundreds of them available from auto traders. That model would appear to show no specific indentation the badge fits to, so that would make it easier.

Comment: @Tetsujin That's interesting. Perhaps that's what was done here. I am curious about your statement though. Why would you want to hide the fact that a car was prestige? Wouldn't that be something an average person would enjoy showing off?

Comment: idk, honestly. I was 2nd owner. The car was originally the dealer demonstrator, so had every option possible to fit. All I really know is that tends to be the trend, hide either the top or the bottom model; presumably for opposing psychological reasons? e.g. no need to brag, vs, I don't want anyone to know I got the cheap one ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Makes sense. Sounds like a nice car too!

Comment: https://gladyssantiago.wordpress.com/2009/04/16/product-displacements-explained-part-1/

Comment: Yup, most of my bags have camera tape over the labels & I never buy any clothing with a camera-visible logo. & @DogLover - yes it was:)

Comment: Back on topic, it does seem to be a US thing. They just don't bother hiding what car it is in the UK. Easiest example, from Eastenders, the Deals on Wheels 2nd hand car dealership - http://eastenders.wikia.com/wiki/Deals_on_Wheels - & that's BBC, who have always traditionally been the ones to cover logos.

Comment: As an alternative to ordering a car without badges in the first place, it's possible to remove and/or cover up logos on cars. I suspect it depends on the budget and timetable and size of the studio/production company. I.e., a larger company may keep badgeless vehicles around for TV shoots so they don't have to plan ahead. A big budget movie might either order custom models or heavily customize the look. An indy film may leave the badges or cover them up. I know that many TV shows shoot at locations in LA by simply covering the existing signs with similar signs that have the fake names on them.

Comment: Yeah, big budget orders 10 of them, 2 to look good, 8 to smash up; some without engines, some with camera rigs bolted on, some with full rally kit seating, some with 2 steering rigs, one for the actor one for the actual driver... etc, etc. I've walked past the garages where they were making the custom jobs for one of the Fast & Furious movies & watched as they wrecked a few making Transformers. Very impressive.Very expensive.

Comment: This might actually be the __European model__, a __[Lancia Voyager](http://cdn1.spiegel.de/images/image-276944-galleryV9-mdgn-276944.jpg)__. That "diamond" does have the shape of the __[Lancia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lancia)__ logo.

Comment: @Oliver_C: Nice find!

Comment: @Oliver_C Oh, wow! That looks spot on! It's interesting that an American show would use a European model though.

Comment: @DogLover Well, it does make it easier to hide the brand if the main part of your viewers doesn't recognize the model.

Comment: Sure it's a Town and Country and not a Dodge Caravan? See: [AutoTrader: Chrysler Town & Country vs. Dodge Grand Caravan: What's the difference?](https://www.autotrader.com/car-reviews/2015-chrysler-town-country-vs-2015-dodge-grand-caravan-whats-the-difference-231456).  (Or, as @Oliver_C notes, maybe a Lancia Voyager, a European model?) I once saw a C T&C next to a DGC and noted how identical everything (including) color was, except minor parts.  I was told they are made in the *same* factory, just changing parts for branding specific components, but otherwise mostly identical in manufacturing.

Answer (score 50):

They modify them. *The Big Bang Theory* is filmed on the Warner Brothers Studio lot. In addition to providing locations for film and television productions, WB offers prop rental services that include design and manufacturing. The studio employs hundreds of craftsmen, designers, costumers, carpenters, metal-workers and mechanics to design any customized props a production may need, from soda cans to batarangs.

This includes vehicles. Almost every vehicle that you see on a production filmed in a studio lot has been customized in some way. At the very least, the original engines will be removed and replaced with electric motors. This is to eliminate the sounds of engines running in the background during filming. On the set of ER, for example, they maintained a fleet of half a dozen ambulances, all fitted with electric motors.

Once a prop, vehicle or costume has been manufactured, it becomes part of the studio's extensive collection, and is usually available for rental by subsequent productions.

You can read more about the facilities and services they offer at [Warner Brothers Studio Facilities](https://studiofacilities.warnerbros.com).

Comment: In the 1960s and 1970s, you'd see in the credits things like "cars provided by Ford/Chrysler/GM".  Mostly on crime dramas like those from Quinn Martin.

Comment: "_At the very least, the original engines will be removed and replaced with electric motors. This is to eliminate the sounds of engines running in the background during filming_. "  This seems like it would be unnecessary in a large number of shoots.  Why would the cars need to be running on set?  Do they regularly have sets built large enough to actually drive around through?  Most times I've seen filming of cars, the cars aren't actually going anywhere.

Comment: @JMac I think in case a car needs to be moved on a small scale such as backing into a garage or driveway.

Answer (score 4):

**This is not modification or de-badging, it is re-branding (rebadging)**

---

This is not a modified or de-badged 2016 Chrysler Town & Country. It is actually a Lancia Voyager S. (2011 or later) But with the stick-on Voyager and the S logos removed.

Just about the exact same car but with another name, and sold in different locations.

- Image of a [2014 Voyager S](http://www.carsinvasion.com/gallery/2014-lancia-voyager-s/2014-lancia-voyager-s-04.jpg).
- [Chrysler Town & Country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysler_Town_%26_Country#Lancia_Voyager_(2011-)) Wikipedia page.
- Wikipedia page about [rebadging](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebadging).

Comment: Ah, the good ol' Town & Country / Caravan / Voyager rebranding, I thought the Voyager died with Plymouth...alas the nonsense continues.

Comment: Yes rtaft. Like many other makes and models.

Comment: "with the stick-on Voyager and the S logos removed"... So, it is debadged.